# Win C#: Install/Run app as administrator without UAC prompt

Tags: c#, exe, prompt, uac, administrator

I have a requirement where application (app1) needs to install / run another application (app2) on user system in non production hours without UAC prompt. I think I can do it with windows service which will elevate my application 1  (app1) which will install my app 2. I worte below code in my console app which will called by windows service :

```
 SecureString ss = ConvertStr.ConvertToSecureString("****");
      DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(userDownloadFolder);
            string[] extensions = new[] { ".bat", ".exe" };
            FileInfo[] Files =
                d.GetFiles()
                     .Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))
                     .ToArray();
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                if (File.Exists(d.FullName + file.Name))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var proc = new Process();
                        proc.StartInfo.FileName = d.FullName + file.Name;
                        proc.StartInfo.Domain = "****";
                        proc.StartInfo.UserName = "**********";
                        proc.StartInfo.Password = ss;
                        proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        proc.Start();
                        proc.WaitForExit();
                        var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
                        proc.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.WriteToFile(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.WriteToFile("File does not exists");
                }
```

Console application runs but it gives Access is denied. But when I tried to install /run by manually right clicking app with user Id & password in UAC prompt it works. Any idea any other way to implement this.

Comment: As what user do you run the service?

Comment: Service run as local system account.

Comment: Then that account might not have the permissions to do what you want. Where exactly do you get the Access denied error?

Comment: Yes I get the access denied error. But when I right click application and run as admin and give same credentials it works.

Comment: Try using those credentials to start the service.

Comment: Done same exception "Access Denied"

Comment: Hard to tell with the information you give. You need to figure out what exactly causes the error. Whether it can't access/find the executable or whether there's really another problem. Maybe the system event log contains additional information. Or try using a debugger.